# Angularjs testing async behaviour inside of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I m trying to make some unit tests with angularjs and I m having some trouble dealing with a function in my controller that calls an asynchronous function of a service and tries to resolve it.

Here's my angular class that I want to test :

```
class Controller(){

  constructor(Service){
    this.service = Service;
    this.billings  = [];
  }

  loadAllBillings(){
    this.service.getAll().then((res)=>{
      this.billings = res.data;
      this.billings.map(x => x * 2 );
    });
  }
}
```

Here's the service that I need to call :

```
class Service(){

  getAll(){
    return $http.get('...');
  }

}
```

And here's where I m blocking :

```
it('should load my billings and multiply ', () => {

  let mock = sinon.mock(service);
  mock.expects('loadAllBillings').returns(new Promise(resolve) => {
    resolve([1, 2, 3]);
  });

  $controller.loadAllGugus();
  expect($controller.billings.length).toEqual(3);

  mock.restore();
  mock.verify();

});
```

I m using sinonjs mock instead of jasmine, I prefer them but it's not the point of my problem.

How can I do to control the fact that $controller.billings has been filled AFTER the async call ?

Actually, I m stroke with the async behaviour of the promise, and when I make my expectations, the object isn't filled...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In addition to my answer, it also looks like you're mocking out the function you're trying to test... you should probably be mocking Service.getAll rather than Service.loadAllBillings?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Sinonjs but typically in the jasmine tests I write, when a function returns a promise, the data that is returned in the promise does not come back until I call `$rootScope.$apply`. So in your example, I would expect that `this.billings` would be empty until you kick off the digest cycle. Here is a snippet from one of my tests. In my beforeEach I set this up

```
fetchUserListInfoDeferred = $q.defer();
spyOn(exgService, 'fetchUserListInfo').and.returnValue(fetchUserListInfoDeferred.promise);
```

And then my tests looks like this

```
it('should populate exgInfo', () => {
        ctrl.getUserListInfo();
        fetchUserListInfoDeferred.resolve(mockData);
        $rootScope.$apply();
        expect(ctrl.exgInfo).toBeDefined();
        expect(ctrl.exgInfo).toBe(mockData);
    });
```

If I don't kick off the digest cycle by calling `$rootScope.$apply` ctrl.exgInfo  will be null because the promise cannot return until the digest cycle has ran. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your controller to return the promise as follows:

```
class Controller(){

  constructor(Service){
    this.service = Service;
    this.billings  = [];
  }

  loadAllBillings(){
    return this.service.getAll().then((res)=>{
      this.billings = res.data;
      this.billings.map(x => x * 2 );
    });
  }
}
```

Then you can update your test to wait for this before checking the result:

```
it('should load my billings and multiply ', () => {

  let mock = sinon.mock(service);
  mock.expects('getAll').returns(new Promise(resolve) => {
    resolve([1, 2, 3]);
  });

  $controller.loadAllBillings().then(function () {
      expect($controller.billings.length).toEqual(3);

      mock.restore();
      mock.verify();
  });

});
```

In Jasmine, you also have to tell it that it's an asynchronous test by taking a "done" parameter into the test function, and calling done(); when the async test is complete, but I'm not familiar with sinon so I don't know if you need to do that as well. If it's the same as Jasmine, the syntax would be:

```
it('should....', (done) => {
    // do test
    // when test complete and all async finished:
    done();
});
```

Comment: I dont want my controller function to return anything , just modify its attributes